# Devise suspendable gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, devise

I want to suspend users in my Rails application. I am using Devise. I had found a gem called `devise_suspendable`, but it requires a migration which include `create_table :users` but I had already used devise initial `create_user` migration and there are a lot of migration after that.

Now how can I implement devise_suspendable?

Or if anyone knows a better way then please recommend.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add the following columns actually,

```
 suspended_at :datetime
 suspension_reason :string
```

instead of  t.suspendable use the add_column command to add these columns to your database

Comment: well i want to keep a flag and check it when a user login.If the flag is set then the user should suspend.Do you have any idea how to do this ?